# How can I parse Google Page Insights output?

Tags: php, laravel

Using [PageInsights API](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/first-app) this is a sample of array I get. How can I replace those things in braces with a link? Do I need to use some complex regular expressions or is there a simpler way?

```
array (size=2)
  'format' => string 'Your page has no redirects. Learn more about {{BEGIN_LINK}}avoiding landing page redirects{{END_LINK}}.' (length=103)
  'args' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'type' => string 'HYPERLINK' (length=9)
          'key' => string 'LINK' (length=4)
          'value' => string 'https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/AvoidRedirects' (length=64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you could do something as simple as:

```
str_replace(
    '{{BEGIN_LINK}}', 
    $a['args'][0]['value'], 
    $a['format']
);
```

Comment: This works, it only feels a little hackish since I need to use str_replace two times

Comment: str_replace also takes a regex, so you could use a pattern that says BEGIN_LINK or END_LINK for example (to knock it over in one shot)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular, just use a filter.

```
<p>{{item.summary.format  |  page_speed_vars}}</p>
```

Filter:

```
app.filter("page_speed_vars", ['$sce', function() {
    return function(str){
        var str = str.replace('{{BEGIN_LINK}}','');
        var str = str.replace('{{END_LINK}}','');
        var str = str.replace('{{NUM_SCRIPTS}}','');
        var str = str.replace('{{NUM_CSS}}','');
        return str;
    }
}]);
```